# JS generator function with preload feature

Tags: javascript

I use a generator function to consume logs and serve it piece by piece. Furthermore the function preload the next logs once the queue is empty. I now like to extend the preload feature so that the preload is triggered once the log array falls below a threshold of 500 entries. I don’t came up with a good solution that’s why I’m asking for help!

```js
async function* getSwaps(project, fromBlock, toBlock, limit) {
    const startBlock = fromBlock;
    const endBlock = toBlock;
    
    let logs = [];
    let queue = [];
    do {
        if (!queue.length && toBlock < endBlock) {
            if (endBlock > fromBlock + limit) {
             toBlock = fromBlock + limit;
          } else {
             toBlock = endBlock;
          }
            const promise = project.getSwaps(fromBlock, toBlock);
            queue.push(promise);
            fromBlock += limit + 1;
        }
        if (!logs.length && queue.length > 0) {
            logs = await queue.shift();
        }
        
        yield logs.shift();
    } while(logs.length > 0 || fromBlock < endBlock);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `queue`. It is enough to know there is an unresolved `promise`. Also, I would expect `promise` to resolve to an **array** of data (for blocks `fromBlock` to `toBlock`), so you shouldn't do `queue.push(promise)`, but push the values from that promised array (individually) to your array (but that could be `logs`).

I think you need two concepts of limits:

- `loadSize`: An indication how many items you will request per call of `project.getSwaps`
- `lowThreshold`: if the size of `logs` drops below this level, a next batch should be requested with a call to `project.getSwaps`, unless all blocks were already requested.

Here is what you could do:

```
async function* getSwaps(project, fromBlock, toBlock, lowThreshold, loadSize) {
    const logs = [];
    let promise;
    while (true) {
        if (!promise && logs.length <= lowThreshold && fromBlock <= toBlock) { // need more
            const doneBlock = Math.min(fromBlock + loadSize - 1, toBlock)
            promise = project.getSwaps(fromBlock, doneBlock);
            fromBlock = doneBlock + 1;
            promise.then(data => { // got more
                logs.push(...data);
                promise = null;
            });
        }
        // Nothing in the logs? Wait for promise to populate it
        if (!logs.length) await promise;
        // Still nothing in the logs? Then we're done
        if (!logs.length) return;
        yield logs.shift();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some small adjustments as it's possible that a block range doesn't return data

```js
async function* getSwaps(pair, fromBlock, toBlock, limit, threshold) { 
   let promise, queue = [];
   do {
      // need more
       if (!promise && queue.length <= threshold && fromBlock <= toBlock) {
           const endBlock = Math.min(fromBlock + limit - 1, toBlock);
           promise = pair.getSwaps(fromBlock, endBlock);
           fromBlock = endBlock + 1;
           promise.then(data => { // got more
            queue.push(...data);
               promise = null;
           });
       }
       // Nothing in the queue? Wait for promise to populate it
       if (!queue.length) await promise;
       // Still nothing? Skip step
       if (queue.length) yield queue.shift();
   } while(fromBlock <= toBlock || queue.length > 0)
```